# Fullcalendar - Not able to display day names in Month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using full calendar 3.4 and trying to show day names in the month view, but nothing seems to work. 
Works fine in Week view though.

[image]

Tried multiple different things and here is my configuration:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        defaultView: 'month',
        weekNumbers: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        selectOverlap: false,
        timeFormat: 'H:mm',
        firstDay: 1,
        views: {
            month: {
              columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd'
        }},


        header: {
            right: 'prev,next today',
            left: 'title',
            center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        } });
```

Any ideas how I can make it to work?

Comment: Day names are shown by default, if you don't set any options at all: http://jsfiddle.net/od1ya08e/

Comment: P.S. columnHeaderFormat was not introduced until 3.8 (as per the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/columnHeaderFormat) . Maybe upgrade to the latest 3.x (3.10 i think) if you want to use this option. Should be no breaking changes, only enhancements. Or use the deprecated columnFormat, which should still work in 3.4 - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/columnFormat

Comment: thought it should be visible by default, tried removing all other options but is still not showing...

Comment: it's not obvious what you've done to make that happen, from the code above. It should be visible. Did you mess with the CSS or anything?

Comment: Demo using your exact code above, on v3.4, no issue: http://jsfiddle.net/od1ya08e/2/ (columnHeaderFormat is just ignored, since it doesn't exist). From the screenshot it looks like you maybe changed some visual styles. I suggest checking your CSS to ensure you haven't accidentally got a conflict or other error causing the text to be invisible.

Comment: Or...do you have any console errors? Perhaps you have an obsolete version of momentJS or something?

Comment: @Oleg I am pretty sure its because of moment.js version. I have created code snippet and everything works fine there if you run snippet you should be able to see day names. Or maybe you are asking for something else ?

Comment: It can't be problem with moment.js because days are shown for week view/day view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What momnet version you are using ? Try this code snippet. I can see day names in the header.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var fullcalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

      defaultView: 'month',
      weekNumbers: true,
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      selectOverlap: false,
      timeFormat: 'H:mm',
      firstDay: 1,
      views: {
        month: {
          columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd'
        }
      },


      header: {
        right: 'prev,next today',
        left: 'title',
        center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked for me. The problem was with FullCalendar sources I was using. Once I replaced last dependency with official CDN it started working fine. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

```
columnFormat: {
 month: 'dddd'
}
```